# Testing PUT in symfony 'php://input' empty

Tags: php, symfony, request, put

In symfony project I have a PUT method and I try to read data like this:

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

When I use Postman it works, the request is in `form-data`:

key: `data`

value: `{"es_title":"edit","es_text":"text edit"}`

But when I try with WebTestCase in project not works, `$data` in PUT method is empty.
I try like this in Test:

```
$data = array(
        "data" => '{"es_title":"edit","es_text":"edit"}');
$this->client->request('PUT', $url, $data, array(), array('HTTP_apikey' => $apikey));
```

Also I try

```
$data = array(
        'data' => json_encode(array(
            'es_title' => 'edit',
            'es_text' => 'edit'
        ))
    );

$this->client->request('PUT', $url, $data, array(), array('HTTP_apikey' => $apikey));
```

How can I do to pass the test?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get data from a PUT I use this inside the controller:

```
$putData = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
```

To make the request from a testCase I use this:

```
    $params = [
        'es_title' => 'edit',
        'es_text' => 'edit',
    ];

    $this->client->request(
        'PUT',
        $url,
        [],
        [],
        [
            'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json',
            'HTTP_X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest'
        ],
        json_encode($params)
    );
```